# (Access VBA touchup) Auto Populating after update based on another textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello I'm trying my best to piece together a code to have all text boxes on the form update to existing records.

All the textboxes are updating beside

> Me.txtSftLvl = myrs!SafteyStockLvl

I am left with the error

> Item Cannot Be Found In The Collection (3265)

I have double checked my naming on the table and textbox itself and they are fine...

Hoping someone would know what im doing wrong or a simpler way of accomplishing my goals.

```
Private Sub txtRcStock_AfterUpdate()

Dim qrystr1 As String
Dim mydb As Database
Dim myrs As DAO.Recordset
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPartDesc"
    

If Me.txtRcStock <> "" Then
        Set mydb = CurrentDb
        qrystr1 = "SELECT Desc FROM qryPartDesc WHERE [PartNumber] = '" & Me.txtRcStock & "'"
        Set myrs = mydb.OpenRecordset(qrystr1)
        If myrs.EOF = False Then
          Me.txtRcCat = myrs!Desc
          
        End If
        
        qrystr1 = "SELECT Price FROM tblRecLog WHERE [PartNumber] = '" & Me.txtRcStock & "'"
        Set myrs = mydb.OpenRecordset(qrystr1)
        If myrs.EOF = False Then
          Me.txtPrice = myrs!Price
        If myrs.EOF = False Then
          Me.txtSftLvl = myrs!SafteyStockLvl
        
        End If
        
         
        
    End Sub
```

Anything helps.

Comment: Looks like your recordset is a query with only a single field ```Price```. So when you go get ```SafteyStockLvl``` (also should that be Safety) it fails, this won't happen on the first and second ```if``` because they are looking at the field in the SELECT Query.

Comment: @Warcupine You are the best! I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much!